# Check time and load content accordingly JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am building a website (personal project) and I'm trying to achieve the following: if the user goes on any page in certain hours (eg: between 22 and 6) it shows a message instead of the desiderd page; if he/she visits the page at other times during the day, the page loads without any message. The message should replace the entire content of the pages in certain hours.

Right now my code works fine on the index, but I want it to become as generic as possible so that the same code can work on all pages.

If this sounds silly it's probably because I am almost a complete newbie in web programming.

Thanks in advance

Here's my code so far:

```
var objDate = new Date();
var hours = objDate.getHours();
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    if(hours >= 06 && hours <= 10){
        $("#content").load("current-page.html"); // Load desired page, so name has to be dynamic I guess (?)
    }
    else{
        $("#content").load("/message.html"); // Load custom message
    }
});
```

Comment: Managing access on the client side can be very hazardous and not very scalable. I would suggest you to handle those access on the server side.

Comment: `hours >= 06 && hours <= 10` checks if the hour is in the **6AM - 10AM** range. Use `hours >= 6 && hours <= 22` for the **6AM - 10PM** range.

Comment: Share you html as well.

Comment: How you do this depends on how your app's routing works. If you're using hashes, you could do something like this: `$("#content").load(location.hash.substr(1));`, if you're using paths, you could do this: `$("#content").load(location.pathname);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load anything else if the user is accessing the page within the defined hours, if I understand correctly.

So just redirect to your message with `window.location = '/message.html';` whenever the conditions are not met, and let the user pass otherwise :

```
var objDate = new Date();
var hours = objDate.getHours();  

if(!(hours >= 06 && hours <= 10)){
    window.location = '/message.html';
}
```